# File ./vendor/autoload.php missing or not readable in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, composer-php

This question is different from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36150377/missing-vendor-autoload-php
I want to contribute to phpmyadmin. I cloned the github repo in my machine using Github Desktop software. I copied the downloaded files in xampp so that I can run phpmyadmin. But when I launch the phpmyadmin page, this error occurs:

> File ./vendor/autoload.php missing or not readable.
>   Most likely you did not run Composer to install library files.

Where can I get that file? I saw something that uses composer create-project command but I don't get that where should I type that command?
I also downloaded phpmyadmin from their website and copy pasted in xampp directory and it worked well. It didn't give any such error.
What should I do?

Comment: Go to the folder, where phpmyadmin is located. Open terminal here (you should see composer.json file here) and type `composer update`. But you need to have a composer installed first: https://getcomposer.org/

Comment: That solved my problem completely. But I have a question that when I downloaded phpmyadmin from their site, there was no vendor folder but still it ran successfully. Why was it required when I downloaded it from github?

Comment: Problably different versions or different library implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This changed as of v4.7.0
https://www.phpmyadmin.net/files/4.7.0/

> Starting with this version, phpMyAdmin uses Composer to manage PHP library dependencies while under development.
>   Users downloading the official source distribution will not notice a difference, however users of the git repository
>   should refer to https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#installing-from-git for details.

Here's the change PR for those interested: github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/pull/11976

Answer (score -1):

When you download or clone phpMyadmin it's missing the `vendor` folder, which is installed by Composer.

Open the phpMyadmin folder and run the `composer install` command. This will download and install third party dependencies and generate the `vendor/autoload.php` file.